# How can you tell if numbers in a list are bigger than 126? If it is bigger the program needs to add 94 to it

Tags: python

I have a list of integers `addOffset`, I want to compare each value of the list with a constant value , in case the value is greater than 126, I need to replace the value by subtracting 94 from that value .

```
#addOffset is my list

if addOffset[0:-1]>126:
    Acode = addOffset[0:-1] - 94
```

Comment: You have to add 94 to each number in that list ?

Comment: You have to add or subtract ?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem and you are attempting to make a caesar cipher.

Comment: Note that `addOffset[0:-1]` in this context is equivalent to `addOffset`

Comment: if the number in the list is bigger than 126 the subtract 94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
for i, element in enumerate(addOffset):
    if element > 126:
        addOffset[i] = element + 94
```

Comment: A few words of explanation would make this example even better.

Comment: While this may not be the most Pythonic way to do this (see the answer referring to [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)) - I think it's probably the best from a "walk before you run" point of view

Comment: Agreed, list comprehensions are definitely more Pythonic.

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension here.

Try,

```
print [x-94 if x > 126 else x for x in addOffset]
```

For example

```
In [1]: addOffset = [12,125,56,456,78,10]
In [2]: print [x-94 if x > 126 else x for x in addOffset]
Out[2]: [12, 31, 56, 362, 78, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
addOffset = [10, 20, 69, 180, 35]

for i in xrange(len(addOffset)):
    if addOffset[i]>126:
        addOffset[i] -= 94   #Incase you wanna subtract else use `+=` operator


>>> print addOffset
>>> [10, 20, 69, 86, 35]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `numpy`, you can write:

```
Acode = np.copy(addOffset)
Acode[Acode > 126] -= 94
```